# Expose Azure DevOps API in Azure Portal App Registration

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

Is it possible to access Azure DevOps APIs which will call APIs like these:

- repositories
  [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1)
- list of users
  [https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://vssps.dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.1-preview.1)

I have create an app and allowed Azure DevOps API [See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHVRK.png)

I know I can create an app in Azure DevOps account. But the reason I want to access from here is due to the multi-tenancy.

What would be the urls to get list of Azure DevOps repositories and users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my test, we can call Azure DevOps rest API with Azure Ad access token. For more details, please refer to the following steps

1. Register an Azure AD application
   [image]
2. Configure applications

   a. Create client secret

   b. Configure permissions

   [image]
3. Get token

get code

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=<app client id>
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/
&response_mode=query
&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&state=12345
```

Get token

```
Post https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
grant_type=authorization_code
&client_id=<>
&code=<>
&redirect_uri=https://localhost:8000/
&scope=499b84ac-1321-427f-aa17-267ca6975798/.default
&client_secret=<>
```

4. Call Rest API

a. list repositories

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=6.1-preview.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

b. List users

```
GET https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/graph/users?api-version=6.1-preview.1
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

For further details about Azure DevOps REST Api, please refer to the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1).

Comment: Thanks Jim Xu. In step 2 I am selecting "Microsoft APIs" and then selecting "Azure DevOps" instead of "APIs my organisation uses". And providing this scope "https://app.vssps.visualstudio.com/user_impersonation". I am able to get access token but when I pass this on to the api request bearer it responds with 302 "Object moved to here"

Comment: Never mind. I was entering wrong scope value. Thank you so much the above is the correct and detailed answer.

Comment: I am getting "Sign in to your account" response while trying to get the code value.